# Always show scrollbars in Sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

How can I configure Sublime text 3 to show horizontal scrollbar always?  It shows horizontal scrollbar only if the lines are too long.

I recently switched from Eclipse and it is kind of bothering me.

**Note:** I googled but could not find any solution so please don't close this as duplicate.